# Problem parsing JSON responce from server

Tags: jquery, json

I'm making a post request to the server and getting back the array of data that I want, but I can't see to access the individual elements and I can't figure out why.

This is the jist of it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post("myscript", { Action: "JQueryReq",  },
  function(data){
   alert(data);
  });
});
```

If I do the above I get back everything I want and it looks like this (in the JS dialog box)

```
[{"val1":null,"val2":null,"val3":null,"Size":"Inches","valu4":null}]
```

But if I change

```
alert(data);
```

to

```
alert(data.Size);
```

I just get "undefined"

I also tried

```
var myjsonreturn = eval(data);
alert(myjsonreturn.Size);
```

I also tried

```
var myjsonreturn = eval('('+data+')');
alert(myjsonreturn.Size);
```

And every time I get undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: Please correct your question title to be something a little more informative than "Another" JSON Parsing question.  It has something to do with accessing specific elements in JQuery.  Please make your title helpful to everyone else with JSON parsing problems.

Comment: Agreed.  This isn't a forum, please ask a real question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `data`? Is it a string? If so, you want to use:

```
eval('('+data+')')[0].Size;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?

```
alert(data[0].Size)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting back as a JSON response is an array with just one cell. Because the array's length is 1 the index will start from the number 0, so you can access the contents like this:

```
alert(data[0].Size);
```

Or, if you want to loop through the values with jQuery's .each():

```
$.each(data[0], function(index, value){
    alert(index + ':' + value);
});
```